# Interactive button in the pdf file

Tags: pdf, microtype, ocg

I thought `.pdf` files generated with LaTeX were static, until I see this interactive button on page 4 of the documentation of `microtype`:

[image]

It is amazing! How is this achieved? Is it possible to build this with LaTeX 2e (using, say, `xelatex`)?

Comment: well the documentation has been created with pdflatex, so yes it is possible. It uses layers, check the ocgx2 package and search here on the site, there are number of examples.

Comment: Also, the documentation file sort of does OCG by hand. You don't want to do that. Use a package, like Ulrike said. The `ocgx2` package is the most modern one, I think, and its [README file](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/ocgx2) includes discussion on how to create links that exposes different layers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this kind of interactivity is achieved with PDF layers.

There are two types of PDF Layers: **OCG**s (Optional Content Groups), whose visibility can be directly set by user interaction in the PDF viewer, and **OCMD**s (Optional Content Membership dictionaries), whose visibility is calculated by logical combination of OCG visibilities during runtime.

Only two of the layers, `protrusion` and `expansion` are created as OCGs. These two layers just take the button captions "Protrusion On" and "Expansion On". Both layers are initially set to "off".

All remaining layers are created as OCMDs, and their visibilities logically depend, during runtime, on the visibilities of the two OCG-type layers `protrusion` and `expansion`. The four, `microtype`-dependent paragraph versions and the button captions "Protrusion Off" and "Expansion Off" live on such OCMD-type layers.

Typeset with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, as `xelatex` does not support expansion; at least three runs are required:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

% inside saveboxes, define layers using OCMDs (optional content membership dictionaries);
% paragraphs on these layers are typeset subject to various combinations of
% protrusion & expansion
\begin{xlrbox}{p=0,e=0}
\begin{ocmd}{\And{\Not{protrusion},\Not{expansion}}}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false,expansion=false}
\kant[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{ocmd}
\end{xlrbox}%
%
\begin{xlrbox}{p=1,e=0}
\begin{ocmd}{\And{protrusion,\Not{expansion}}}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true,expansion=false}
\kant[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{ocmd}
\end{xlrbox}%
%
\begin{xlrbox}{p=0,e=1}
\begin{ocmd}{\And{\Not{protrusion},expansion}}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false,expansion=true}
\kant[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{ocmd}
\end{xlrbox}%
%
\begin{xlrbox}{p=1,e=1}
\begin{ocmd}{\And{protrusion,expansion}}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true,expansion=true}
\kant[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{ocmd}
\end{xlrbox}%
%
% define layers using OCGs (optional content groups) and OCMDs
\noindent\switchocg{protrusion}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\begin{ocg}{protrusion}{protrusion}{off}Protrusion On\end{ocg}}%
  \begin{ocmd}{\Not{protrusion}}Protrusion Off\end{ocmd}%
}
\quad
\switchocg{expansion}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\begin{ocg}{expansion}{expansion}{off}Expansion On\end{ocg}}%
  \begin{ocmd}{\Not{expansion}}Expansion Off\end{ocmd}%
}\\[2ex]

% insert saved paragraphs
\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{p=0,e=0}}%
\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{p=1,e=0}}%
\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\xusebox{p=0,e=1}}%
\noindent\xusebox{p=1,e=1}%

\end{document}
```