# Toggle button (and functionality) to change between light and dark mode of pdf

Tags: color, packages, printing, displaystyle, button

I would like to have both light and dark mode style in the same pdf.
The light mode would be used when the reader wants to print the document while the dark mode will be used for reading the document on  screen.

I would insert manually edited light color images to be displayed in light mode and dark color images for dark mode. I would like to have a style with dark page background color and light text colors for the dark mode.

I don't know if it is possible to insert a toggle button in the pdf and have different layers (maybe) show up or hide depending on the mode chosen, light or dark.

How do I proceed? Is it even possible?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible in *TeX. Some PDF viewers have options to a) invert PDF colors and/or b) change the background / text colour. Would this solve the problem? Alternatively, you could produce one PDF document for each case. Or, frankly this task seems best for a simple HTML page.

Comment: Looks like toggle buttons work with boxes on layers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585417/interactive-button-in-the-pdf-file