# How to create a toggle switch?

Tags: pdftex

I have created two commands `\lightmode` and `\darkmode` that each change the color scheme of my pdf to match light mode or dark mode. I would like to create a toggle switch in the pdf that allows the user to move between the modes. How can I write code that achieves the following:

```
if switch is on:
    \darkmode
else:
    \lightmode
```

I would also like my pdf to be in dark mode by default.

Note: By switch, I mean any kind of interactive button that would achieve the above functionality.

Comment: the commands are in your source, you can't really reformat the pdf from within the pdf, you need to produce two pdf one light and one dark

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You cannot have a button in your PDF that generates the PDF anew using LaTeX. You'd need to create a PDF with two layers which you show or hide or a JavaScript-flavoured color changing mechanism or something similar. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585417/47927 which suggests `ocgx2`.

Comment: This has been asked before: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611484/47927

Comment: Some PDF readers allow you to toggle light/dark from within the reader itself, regardless of the PDF. That is the most you can expect.